# CSS nth-child(n) not responding after being appended with jQuery

Tags: jquery, css, pseudo-element

my `nth-child()` pseudo element isn't working on the elements.

- It works just fine on [**JSFiddle**](https://jsfiddle.net/uvp4zvvw/2/) with compiled CSS **YET NOT** with SCSS.
- On my machine it doesn't work with either CSS nor SCSS.
- Please also notice that `.sketchBoxGame` nth-child() doesn't work at all.
- Does this have anything to do with jQuery creating and populating the elements without considering pseudo-elements?

What's going on here?

**HTML:**

```
<div id="game" class="container-fluid">
    <div class="row">
        <div class="container-sketch text-center"></div>
    </div>
</div>
```

**CSS:**

```
    .sketchBoxGame {
        width: 100px;
        height: 100px;
        //background-color: white;
        border: 1px solid black;
        display: inline-block;
        vertical-align: top;
        margin: 5px;
        &:nth-child(2) {
          background-color: #3c763d;
        }
      }
      .sketchBoxIcon{
        width: 100px;
        height: 100px;
        display: inline-block;
        vertical-align: top;
        margin: 5px;
        background-color: #5bc0de;
}
```

**JS:**

```
var main = function () {
        iconBoxes();
        gameBoxes();
    };
    //Miki - here you can determine how many boxes you want per height/width
    var gameBoxWidth = 3;
    var gameBoxHeight = 3;

    var iconBoxWidth = 3;
    var iconBoxHeight = 1;

    var containerSketch = '.container-sketch';
    var sketchBoxGame = '.sketchBoxGame';
    var sketchBoxIcon = '.sketchBoxIcon';

    var gameBoxes = function () {
        $('sketchBoxGame').remove();
        for (var i = 0; i < gameBoxHeight; i++) {
            for (var j = 0; j < gameBoxWidth; j++) {
                $(containerSketch).append('<div class="sketchBoxGame"></div>');
            }
            $(containerSketch).append('<br>');
        }
    };
    var iconBoxes = function () {
        for (var i = 0; i < iconBoxHeight; i++) {
            for (var j = 0; j < iconBoxWidth; j++) {
                $(containerSketch).append('<div class="sketchBoxIcon"></div>');
            }
            $(containerSketch).append('<br>');
        }

    };

    $(document).ready(main);
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

> Please also notice that .sketchBoxGame nth-child() doesn't work at
>   all.

That's because there is no .sketchBoxGame element that is 2nd child... They are put after 3 .sketchBoxIcon elements. I am guessing that you want to flag the 2nd element of each row, to do so, simply wrap every elements of a row in a container.

```
var gameBoxes = function () {
    $('sketchBoxGame').remove();
    for (var i = 0; i < gameBoxHeight; i++) {
        var $row = $(containerSketch).append('<div>');
        for (var j = 0; j < gameBoxWidth; j++) {
            $row.append('<div class="sketchBoxGame"></div>');
        }
    }
};
```

I had forgot, but you can use the (an + b) formula in nth-child like so

```
.sketchBoxGame:nth-child(4n+2) {
    background-color: #3c763d;
}
```

This targets every 2nd element of every 4 elements repetitions. (It is 4 because you got three sketchBoxGame + one BR element.

Comment: I would like to change my `gameBoxes` function as to your suggestion, but how would you select them afterwards? `row.gameBoxes:nth-child(5)` would select the middle box in the 2nd row?

Comment: It all depends exactly on what you want to select? All the second boxes or just the first one? If only the first one, keep your function as is and just put nth-child(6) (3 icon + BR + 2elemtn)

Comment: I actually figured it out, not into (Xn + Y) but it does follow a certain pattern. You helped me the most, thanks.

Answer (score 2):

For sure, its not related to creating elements with JQuery. Its all about CSS.

If you select the element with class's pseudo  element, it acts like you selected related div.

In this example you can see what I am trying to tell;

```css
.example2:nth-child(2) {
 color: red;
}
```

```html
<div class="example1">x</div>
<div class="example2">x</div>
<div class="example2">x</div>
<div class="example2">x</div>
```

Comment: I upvoted your answer but I still can't understand why `.sketchBoxIcon` `nth-child()` is working and `.sketchBoxGame` `nth-child()` isn't working...

Comment: For example, try to type . sketchBoxGame:nth-child(5) (dont forget your br is counting as a child..), . -By the way, this is not true type of using...-